# karma + jasmine + angular + ui router - unit test for a state with parent property

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular module, lets say, moduleA. I am using angular ui-router to define the states.

moduleA has state `stateA` with `resolve`.

```
$stateProvider
                .state('stateA', {
                    abstract: true,
                    parent: 'secure',
                    templateUrl: baseUrl + '/templates/root.html',
                    controller: 'rootCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        value1: [ 'StateService', function ( StateService) {
                            return StateService.getValue1();
                        }],

                        value2: ['Service2', function(Service2) {                               
                                return Service2.getValue2();
                            }]
                    }
                })
```

Then, I have another module "moduleB" in which I define state `stateB` with parent property `stateA`.

```
$stateProvider
                .state('stateB', {
                    parent: 'stateA',
                    abstract: true,
                    templateUrl : baseUrl+'/templates/stateB.html'
                })
                .state('stateB.details', {
                    url: '/stateB/details/:param1/:param2',
                    resolve : {
                        value3 : ['$localStorage', '$stateParams', function($localStorage, $stateParams){
                            return $localStorage.value3[$stateParams.param1];
                        }]
                    },
                    views : {
                        'view1' : {
                            templateUrl : baseUrl+'/templates/view1.html',
                            controller: 'View1Ctrl'
                        },
                        'view2' : {
                            templateUrl : baseUrl+'/templates/view2.html',
                            controller : 'View2Ctrl'
                        }
                    }
                })
```

In my Karma - Jasmine unit test for moduleB, I have

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $state, $injector, $httpBackend) {
            rootScope = $rootScope;
            state = $state;
            injector = $injector;
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;

        }));


        it('should be an abstract state', function(){
            var s = state.get('stateB');
            expect(s.abstract).toBeTruthy();
        });
```

Test fails with error `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 's.abstract')`

If I comment the line `parent: 'stateA'`, from `stateB`'s definition,  test will pass with success.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Inspect `s` when it runs - what's there? Try making the `abstract` property a string `'abstract': true`. Set a breakpoint and follow `state.get` to see what's happening.

Comment: I'm guessing that state just isn't defined then. Try doing a `state.get()`, that will give you all of the configured states - is `stateB` there?. Are you sure moduleB is loaded when the test runs?

Comment: Fixed.  I was loading "moduleB" in my tests but not moduleA. I fixed my issue by loading "moduleA" in my tests.  I had to add beforeEach(module('moduleA'));

Comment: Yep, that would do it. If you add that as the answer, you'll be able to mark this question as answered in a day or two.

Comment: Thank you. Just added it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. I was loading "moduleB" in my tests but not moduleA. I fixed my issue by loading "moduleA" in my tests. I had to add beforeEach(module('moduleA'));